# DateTime.Parse takes min date value if null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, nullable

I have an asp.net application in which I have a textbox to enter datetime value and it is saved in the database.

Now when I am trying to retrieve the date, it shows 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM if the date is null.

```
this.FirstReceivedDate = DateTime.Parse(dr["FirstReceivedDate"].ToString());
```

Apologies, requirement changed. Now I want to show blank ('') if FirstReceivedDate is null.

How can I do that?

Comment: is it actually null in the database?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse()` would throw an exception if it is a `DBNull.Value` coming out of the database.  I suspect you have that bottom line datetime in the actual database table..?  Please verify.

Comment: I don't believe the data in the database matches what you think they are. I am unable to reproduce this case with the `null`, empty strings, etc. values. Please verify what `dr["FirstReceivedDate"].ToString()` returns.

Comment: Note that `FirstRecievedDate` should be a `Date` type column in your database. In that case you don't need to Parse it. Just use `this.FirstReceivedDate = = dr.Field<DateTime>("FirstReceivedDate");`

Comment: Yes, It is null in database. Also, the field is a datetime in database.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the below:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dr["FirstReceivedDate"].ToString());
this.FirstReceivedDate = date != DateTime.MinValue ? date : DateTime.Now;
```

since it is parsing correctly, this ought to work.

Alternatively, if you want a value when the date is null, you can try something like this:

```
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParse(dr["FirstReceivedDate"], out date))
    this.FirstReceivedDate = date != DateTime.MinValue ? date : DateTime.Now;
else
    this.FirstReceivedDate = DateTime.Now; // or whatever you want to do if "FirstReceivedDate" is not a valid date.
```

Comment: The OP's `DateTime.Parse()` doesn't have a formatting exception, therefore `DateTime.TryParse()` wouldn't return `false` for the bad condition.

Comment: This is a naive try, if the dr["FirstReceivedDate"] is null you will get an exception when the tostring is executed ahhhhh

Comment: @Juan we don't really know what the user wants to do if the field is null. does he actually want a value, or let it bomb out?

Answer (score 1):

DateTime variables (along with all other value types) cannot be null (unless you explicitly declare them as nullable), as they have to hold a value. (You have now said it *is* nullable)

The fix you require is quite easy - you can just check for the null value of the field in the datarow and assign appropriately a null DateTime if it is, otherwise assign the type-safe database value using the `DataRow.Field<T>` method:

```
this.FirstReceivedDate = dr["FirstReceivedDate"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : dr.Field<DateTime>("FirstReceivedDate");
```

Actually thinking about it you should just be able to do the following to propagate the null value (untested):

```
this.FirstReceivedDate = dr.Field<DateTime?>("FirstReceivedDate");
```

As you stated that you want a blank string if the database value is null, then just when you display it you can just do a check on the null value of the DateTime:

```
textBox1.Text = this.FirstReceivedDate == null ? "" : this.FirstReceivedDate.ToString();
```

Comment: I have declared the variable as nullable. Would it be the same fix though?

Comment: I have updated my answer now you have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.FirstReceivedDate = DateTime.Parse(dr["FirstReceivedDate"].ToString());

if (this.FirstReceivedDate == DateTime.MinValue)
    this.FirstReceivedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Test to see if `FirstReceivedDate` is equal to the minimum value for DateTime (which you specified in your question).  If so, simply set it to the current date/time.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dr["FirstReceivedDate"].ToString());     
this.FirstReceivedDate = date = =default(DateTime) ? DateTime.Now : date;
```

The real question here is **why are you receiving 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM when you say the datetime is nullable?**, you should receive DBNull, check your database, the field should accept nulls.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this extension method to try to convert to datetime, if the function return null then the value is not a valid datetime

```
     public static DateTime? ToDateTimeCheck2(this string valor)
{
       var isDate = true;

        DateTime dt;
        isDate  = DateTime.TryParse(valor, out dt);

        if (isDate)
            return dt;
        else
        return null;


}
```

Then in your code you can say

```
this.FirstReceivedDate =( dr["FirstReceivedDate"].ToDatetimeCheck2() == null)? "" : dr["FirstReceivedDate"].ToDatetimeCheck2();
```

Other option with out the extension method:

```
 string t = "123";

            DateTime result;

            string testing = (DateTime.TryParse(t,out result ))? result.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: I have used this code in a lot of projects with out problem. The idea here is to create this extension method in a class as a helper. If you are working with a ORM mapper like Entity Framework and you are adding a record if the value in this case date time is null or empty then you will send null to the object of entity framework is this will help the framework to react because the value is null.

Comment: tbh `DateTime.TryParse` does the same thing.

Comment: TryParse will return a bool value indicating if the conversion was successful. The extension method is a helper to avoid a lot of code is this testing.

Comment: it also passes out the parsed date if the conversion was succesful, and if it was unsuccessful the date is null.

Comment: Using tryparse if the test is not good the out variable will get 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
The out variable is not nullable.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DataRow dbField = dr["FirstReceivedDate"];

this.FirstReceivedDate = dbField == null 
    ? String.Empty 
    : dbField.ToString() ;
```

Comment: I don't think you can assign `String.Empty` to a `DateTime`. You're also doing 2 parse operations when you really only need one.

Comment: OP shows target field is a string. Yes, you could create a variable instead. Updated answer.

Comment: It returns an error saying "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime and 'string'"

Comment: Updated. Had a misplaced paren.

Comment: @BillMartin depending on the culture you may need to specify the date format in the `.ToString()` call.

Comment: Updated to check for null.

Answer (score -1):

Below code worked.

```
string date = dr["FirstReceivedDate"].ToString();
this.FirstReceivedDate = date == "" ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(date);
```

Thanks to everyone for help.